# JMeter to test java rest Api

Tags: json, jmeter, java

How can i pass the json for post method if my json is like:

```
{
"REQUEST":{"REQUEST_BODY":{"Account_Name":"ak"}}
}
```

It gives me an error at time of parsing json value

In postman it run properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTTP Request use **Body Data** tab and of course fill-in Server Name, Port Number, Path and Update Method if needed:

[image]

And under HTTP Request add a Header Manager:

[image]

And add to it required headers:

[image]

Note Content-type might be different for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your request works in Postman you can just record it in JMeter:

1. Configure JMeter for recording, the fastest way is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File - Templates - Recording - Create`
   - Expand `Workbench - HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start
2. Configure Postman for recording. You can "tell" Postman which proxy server to use (JMeter in your case) via `--proxy-server` command-line argument

   ```
   C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Postman\app-x.x.x\Postman.exe --proxy-server=localhost:8888
   ```
3. Execute your request in Postman
4. JMeter will capture the request and store it under `Test Plan - Thread Group - Recording Controller`

References:

- [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [How to configure Postman Native Client App to use an external proxy](http://blog.eviltester.com/2016/12/how-to-configure-postman-native-client.html)